# Print Not Adjacent in Google Sheet

Tags: printing, google-drive-api, spreadsheet

I'm having issues printing not-adjacent columns in Google Sheets. I've upgraded to Google Sheet so the Ctrl Click works, and print -> selection, but these are the results.[image]Why yes, I do love triple monitor, and credits to dropbox for easy screenshot tool. Anyway, these are the results I get every time. I'd rather not have to move back to Excel because of the ease of use, and just all right wherever I need it ease of Google Drive, but if I have to, I will. Also, just tested, I get the same results from Excel. Any ideas other than new sheet to pull columns over? Trying to make it so a non-technical can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't know the exact and pure answer for this, I can suggest a workaround:

Hide those columns that you won't need (in this case - Select Column D/Right Clik/Hide Column), and then select everything from A to E column. (Of course D will remain hidden).

If you do it this way you will only get the "visible" part printed.

I admit that it's not that convenient, but anyway hope it helped.

Comment: I've attempted this, and I do... "like" the workaround, and if it was for anyone else, I'd be fine with that. It's just a stupid user and this is a thing where she forgets a column is hidden and thinks "Google broke my spreadsheet" type deal.